# Tokenize Argument in custom shell

Tags: c

I have quick questions.

I'm creating a basic custom shell, and I have a question regarding token.
I tokenize the input string from the user into `args[i]`

My question is:

```
$ cd my_file
// means that args[0] is 'cd' and args[1] is 'my_file'

$ ls
// means that args[0] is 'ls' but what is args[1]? Is it NULL or '\0' or what?
```

what is `args[1]` in ls? Is it `NULL` or `'\0'` or what?

I'm planning to do a strcmp for the `args[i]`. thank you

Comment: You are implementing the tokenization so it is up to you to define that any way you like. But the standard C `argv` passed to main has `argv[argc]` set to `NULL` if that's what you are asking about. So, for the standard C `main`, if the command is `ls` then `argv[0]` is `"ls"` and `argv[1]` is `NULL`.

Comment: @kaylum that was exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you. I was about to say that argv[1] is '\0'

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing the tokenization so it is up to you to define that any way you like. But the standard C `argv` passed to main has `argv[argc]` set to `NULL` if that's what you are asking about. So, for the standard C `main`, if the command is `ls` then `argv[0]` is `"ls"` and `argv[1]` is `NULL`.
                    – kaylum